# Checkbox Alignment problem when checked - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, alignment

When checkboxes are unchecked, the alignment is in a straight line.But, if the checkbox is checked,the box moves towards left.
I want the boxes to be aligned in a straight line whether checked or not.
Please mention fix for this issue.

```css
[Image- Checkbox moves when checked][1] input[type=checkbox][_ngcontent-c13],
.tbl-chkBx[_ngcontent-c13] {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  vertical-align: initial;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<td _ngcontent-c13="" class="tbl-chkBx">

  <input _ngcontent-c13="" class="form-check-input position-static ng-untouched ng-valid" formcontrolname="isSelected" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="isSelected">

</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely an issue related to the width and height of the elements.
This should fix it:

```
input[type="checkbox"] { 
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
  -o-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```